# How do I stop Alfred from stealing command+shift+\?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu, alfred

I use the program Alfred2, unfortunately it keeps trying to steal the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. How do I stop it from doing so? It conflicts with other apps such as Aperture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, one of the workflow hijacked the shortcut. Has nothing to do with Alfred itself.

Comment: Sounds like you've already found your answer, but as a tip for the future, there's a search box at the top of workflows so when you feel your hotkey might be in use, type one of the characters there to bring up any workflows that use it. - Vero (one half of the Alfred team)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think Alfred uses that shortcut by default; that’s being used by 1Password for me. Do you mean <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (which takes you to the previous path used in the file browser?).

All the keyboard shortcuts that Alfred uses can be customised in the preferences. To get to the preferences, open Alfred, and press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

If my guess is correct, then you want to select **Features** > **File Search** > **Navigation** and change the shortcut associated with the **Previous Path**. Click on the box to the right of that label, and either press a new keyboard shortcut you want to use, or press delete to just unassign <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

These instructions work in Alfred 2; I don’t have a copy of Alfred 1 to hand so I can’t remember how it works in that version. (And this assumes my guess is right, of course.)

Comment: No I mean specifically cmd + shift + \. Which is set album pick in Aperture. It works when I quite Alfred2, but doesn't work when I launch it.

Comment: @erotsppa: ah, I’ve just read your answer. Glad you found an answer. :)